# Only handle URLs that have query string, and pass the rest to IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, static-files

I have this requirement. A static website exists that serves static content, like images, audios, videos, etc.

A sample URL is like this:

```
https://storage.example.com/files/galleries/last-trip/picture.jpg
```

This is served by IIS now, and the performance is amazing. Now I want to be able to dynamically resize it, in case query strings exist.

```
https://storage.example.com/files/galleries/last-trip/picture.jpb?w=100&h=200
```

The problem is performance. I don't want to lose IIS's default capability to serve static files.

I know that I can use `StaticFileMiddleware` of ASP.NET Core. But I prefer to have this behavior:

1. Check incoming URL. If it has query string, process it.
2. If not, let IIS serve.

Is this possible in ASP.NET Core? How?

Comment: Do you want this effect？https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2011/05/dynamic-image-resizing-module-v3